# Django can not send email when deployed by nginx+uwsgi+Django

Tags: django, email

I use Django to send email,everything is OK when running on development environment, which uses command "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8100". But in the production environment which deployed by nginx+uwsgi+Django do not work.

Here is the code:

```
#Email settings
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.exmail.qq.com'
EMAIL_PORT='465'
EMAIL_HOST_USER='sender@qq.cn'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='password'
EMAIL_USE_SSL=True
RECEIVE_EMIAL_LIST=['receiver@qq.com']

send_mail('subject','content',setting.EMAIL_HOST_USER,setting.RECEIVE_EMIAL_LIST, fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: did u solve it? if yes how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

1. `EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.qq.com'`
2. change `EMAIL_PORT='465'` to `EMAIL_PORT = 587`, with no quotes.
3. `EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'abc@qq.com'` # try to use your real email address.
4. `RECEIVE_EMIAL_LIST=['receiver@qq.com']` to `RECEIVE_EMIAL_LIST=['receiver@qq.com'**,**]` # add a comma at the end of the list is a good habit.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that your production environment has the same network settings as the development environment?

Have you tried to ping or telnet the SMTP server from production?

Is possible that the production host is in a DMZ or in a subnet that has restricted access to the SMTP server you are trying to reach.